# Sharepoint Timezone Change Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

I need to change the timezone for all sites within sharepoint. I run this code that i found online.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

#function to change Timezone regional settings of a SharePoint Online site
Function Set-SPOnlineTimeZone([String]$SiteURL,[String]$TimezoneName,[PSCredential]$Cred)
{
     Try
     {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Set up the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $credentials

        #Get the Root web from given URL
        $Web = $Ctx.web
        $Ctx.Load($Web)

        #Get the Time zone to update
        $Timezones = $Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones
        $Ctx.Load($Timezones)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $NewTimezone = $Timezones | Where {$_.Description -eq $TimezoneName}

        #Update the timezone of the site
        $Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $NewTimezone
        $Web.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        Write-host -f Green "Timezone has been updated for "$Web.Url

        #Get all subsites of the web
        $Ctx.Load($Web.Webs)
        $Ctx.executeQuery()

        #Iterate through each subsites and call the function recursively
        Foreach ($Subweb in $Web.Webs)
        {
            #Call the function to set Timezone for the web
            Set-SPOnlineTimeZone -SiteURL $Subweb.URL -TimezoneName $TimezoneName -Cred $AdminCredentials
        }
   }
    Catch [System.Exception]
    {
        Write-Host -f Red $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

#Config parameters for SharePoint Online Admin Center and Timezone description
$AdminSiteURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$TimezoneName ="(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat"

#Get credentials to connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Tenant Admin
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $AdminCredentials

#Get all Site Collections
$SitesCollection = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

#Iterate through each site collection
ForEach($Site in $SitesCollection)
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Setting Timezone for Site Collection:"$Site.URL

    #Call the function to set Timezone for the site
    Set-SPOnlineTimeZone -SiteURL $Site.URL -TimezoneName $TimezoneName -cred $AdminCredentials
}


#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/sharepoint-online-change-time-zone-using-powershell.html#ixzz68Mt3Xrom
```

I gett the following error

```
At line:10 char:16
+ ... edentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCr ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system."
At line:19 char:1
+ $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdcrlException

An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested..
At line:22 char:1
+ $Timezones | Select ID, Description
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Share...lient.TimeZone]:<GetEnumerator>d__0) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

The account that i'm using is admin account for office365 (globle admin)however it has 2fa. I'm assumuing there needs to be some other method for this but no idea. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According the Microsofts documentation on the Connect-SP* command, if your account is using 2FA you'll want to omit the credentials from your connect statement and let it prompt you for credentials manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice?view=sharepoint-ps

See example 3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MFA in your environment, I would suggest you use sharepoint pnp powesrhsell.

You could refer to the below articles for more:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Using-SharePoint-Client-Side-Object-Model-with-PowerShell-and/m-p/92734

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-csom-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-with-multi-factor-authentication-enabled